# Having trouble with a fixed element on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a layout where there is a horizontal menu under the logo, and when the user scrolls past the logo the menu becomes fixed at the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    $el = $('#menu');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
        $('#content-text').css({'margin-top': '50px'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '100px'});
        $('#content-text').css({'margin-top': '0px'});
    }
});
```

In doing so I also have to change the `margin-top` of the main content, otherwise it jumps.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7R89x/

While the fixed menu appears to be working, when I change the margin on the content section it now overlaps the footer at the bottom of the page. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not really seeing the problem you describe...the footer and the content don't appear to be overlapping (at least in Chrome, and IE8).

Comment: @Serlite it is happening in Firefox (I'm using v 29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way. *OR* - one of the 2 ways below. If you know the heights for sure, you can just add and remove class. If you don't, you can just query them. Here is [a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Gmxxk/)

I think the real issue is that FF is strict, and your major blocks aren't really organized box-model wise. If you float them all left and make them width 100% etc, they will stack nicely. The whole table-cell thing is whack. You are better off with the consistency of floats.

### HTML

```
<header>
    header
</header>

<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi id dicta asperiores placeat tempore doloribus eius consequuntur vero libero fugiat quidem officia. Quae est temporibus non ad reiciendis excepturi doloribus!</p>

    <ul>
        <li>to show scroll</li>
        <li>etc.</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, nav, section {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: red;
    min-height: 100px;
}

nav {
    background: lightblue;
}

.menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    background: orange;
    min-height: 1200px
}

.fixed-header nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.fixed-header section {
    background: lime;
    /* you could set margin here, if you know the nav height for sure */
}
```

### jQUERY

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    var navHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > headerHeight ) {

        $('body').addClass('fixed-header');
        $('section').css({
            'margin-top' : navHeight 
        });

    } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= headerHeight ) {

        $('body').removeClass('fixed-header');
        $('section').css({
            'margin-top' : 0 
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason you add that margin-top: 50px to content-text?

removing that just works fine.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    $el = $('#menu');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});

    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
        $('#menu').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '100px'});

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7R89x/2/

Comment: It doesn't work (I'm looking at it in Firefox 29), because the content jumps up 50 px.

Comment: what about using padding-top: 50px instead?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing is good, and the problem you are facing is because the height of the `content-text` is `100` of the outer-div(`content`)  which is 100%. But you are specifying a margin of let's say `5%`. Then it will cause an overflow 5%.. As you are getting.

So my advise change the height as well..
Updated link:
http://jsfiddle.net/7R89x/1/

code:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
    $('#menu').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
    $('#content-text').css({'margin-top': '5%','height':'95%'});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
    $('#menu').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '100px'});
    $('#content-text').css({'margin-top': '0px','height':'100%'});
}
```

OR

Just

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed') {
    $('#menu').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
    $('#content').css({'margin-top': '50px'});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed') {
    $('#menu').css({'position': 'static', 'top': '100px'});
    $('#content').css({'margin-top': '0px'});
}
```

works flawlessly..

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7R89x/3/

Comment: Is there a more seamless solution? Changing the margin to a percent instead of a fixed number will cause the content to jump... It just isn't very fluid.

Comment: The problem by adjusting the position this way is you take the menu out of the document flow, making the rest of the content jump.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt your updated link (at least in Firefox 29) still causes the content to jump up 50 px... Notice how the first sentence disappears entirely as soon as you reach the menu.

Comment: Not in mine (FF-30), even the answer by @Edward works fine. I think issue is with your browser.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt of course the issue is with my browser, that is what I'm trying to fix.